# C# check for Vowel

Tags: c#, keypress

I want to check if the user input is a vowel. If any other key is pressed, an error should be shown. Here's what i have so far. How can I add the other Keys?
Current output:
"Key pressed" A

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ConsoleKeyInfo A;
        while (true)
        {
            A = Console.ReadKey();
            if (A.Key == ConsoleKey.A);
            { 
              Console.WriteLine("A"); 
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
 protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
            {
                if (keyData == Keys.F3)
                {
                    //do something;
                }
                if(keyData ==Keys.Escape)
                {
                    //do something;
                }
                if(keyData ==Keys.F2)
                {
                    //do something;
                }
                return false;
            }
```

Comment: That looks like a solid answer! although i get the error The name 'Keys' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @user3446201 i think im out of scope can you tell where to place this code?